# RPCPORT and --rpcport not working in Latest version: 0.18.0

Tags: bitcoin-core, rpc-error-25

We are using bitcoin core RPC Endpoint to broadcast transaction over network, It was working perfectly till version 0.17.0 but in latest version 0.18.0 RPCPORT and --rpcport is not working.

Please let us know is there any way to start RPC port on version 0.18.0

Answer (score 1):

See the 0.18 release notes (https://bitcoin.org/en/release/v0.18.0#configuration-option-changes):

> The `rpcallowip` option can no longer be used to automatically listen on all network interfaces. Instead, the rpcbind parameter must be used to specify the IP addresses to listen on. Listening for RPC commands over a public network connection is insecure and should be disabled, so a warning is now printed if a user selects such a configuration.